# Total does not get displayed in a visual force page

Tags: visualforce, controller, pdf

Can any on help me out how to get the total display for the quarter in a visual force page which is in a PDF format .The Column count is not getting display for any quarters.Any help very much appreciated.

VF CODE :

```
    <tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data" >SubTotal :</td>
                         <td colspan="0"  class="header-table-data"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl},<br/>${!Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl},<br/></td>
<td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl},<br/>${!Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl},<br/></td>
                         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl},<br/>${!Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl},<br/></td>
                         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl},<br/>${!Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl},<br/></td>
                         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!QtyGrndTtl},<br/>${!AmtGrndTtl},<br/></td>

                         </tr>
```

Code :

```
for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast1 : opflist) {
         integer j = 0;

    for(j=0; j<3; j++){

    // replace oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name[i] with the product name string
    Integer Qty01 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
   // Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl+=integer.valueOf(opflist[j].gmod__Quantity__c);

    //qty01 = qty01 == null ? qty01 : 0;

    Integer Qty02 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty03 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty04 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty11 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty12 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty13 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty14 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty21 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty22 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty23 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty24 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));

    //System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@123 ++ ' + QtyGrndTtl);

    Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty01 + Qty11 + Qty21; //reset to zero each yr.
    Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl+=integer.valueOf(opflist[j].gmod__Quantity__c);
    System.debug('Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ++ ' +Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl);

    //Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty02 + Qty12 + Qty22;
    Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl = 0 + (Qty02 == null ? 0 : Qty02 ) + (Qty12 == null ? 0 : Qty12 )   + (Qty22 == null ? 0 : Qty22 ) ;
    Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty03 + Qty13 + Qty23;
    Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty04 + Qty14 + Qty24;

    //QtyGrndTtl = QtyGrndTtl.add(Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl);
    list<integer>QtyGrndTtl = new list<integer>();
    QtyGrndTtl.add(Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl);


     System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ++ ' + QtyGrndTtl);



    // replace oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name[i] with the product name string
    decimal amt01 = Amount1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt02 = Amount2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt03 = Amount3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt04 = Amount4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt11 = Amount1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt12 = Amount2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt13 = Amount3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt14 = Amount4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt21 = Amount1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt22 = Amount2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt23 = Amount3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt24 = Amount4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);

    Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt01 + amt11 + amt21; //reset to zero each yr.
    Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt02 + amt12 + amt22;
    Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt03 + amt13 + amt23;
    Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt04 + amt14 + amt24;
   // AmtGrndTtl[j] = Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl;
   //Decimal[]  AmtGrndTtl = new Integer[3];
   list<decimal>AmtGrndTtl = new list<decimal>();
    AmtGrndTtl.add(Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl);
     System.debug('amt############# ++ ' +AmtGrndTtl);

    j++;

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain which variable is not visibile ? If possible variable declaration as well and apex code is called when ? in action method or some getter ?

Comment: @ Jitendra Zaa:For Quarter1 im using as Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl to get the column  total for quarter1,but the total is not getting displayed on the vf page.Similarly for other quarters.